# Form validation using Abide

Tags: javascript, validation, zurb-foundation, abide

I am using foundation css for front end design and how can I use Abide(form validator).

Example:.. If I need to allow only 10 characters for the field Phone number..

Correct me If I am wrong as I am a newbie to use foundation and web dev.

I have already tried doing this... this does not work..

```
version : '5.3.3',

settings : {
  live_validate : true,
  focus_on_invalid : true,
  error_labels: true, // labels with a for="inputId" will recieve an `error` class
  timeout : 1000,
  patterns : {
    alpha: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
    alpha_numeric : /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/,
    integer: /^[-+]?\d+$/,

    // modified here

    cvv : /^([0-9]){3,4}$/,   \\ I have just copied the above line and renamed the pattern as "cv"
    cv : /^([0-9]){3,4}$/'   \\the pattern cvv works but the same when I copy pasted and renamed to cv does not work.

    `
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by looking at their documentation (here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html)

there you will learn how to add a custom pattern (since you have some custom requirements).

You will have to define a new pattern, maybe call it phoneNumber

```
$(document)
  .foundation({
    abide : {
      patterns: {
        phoneNumber: ^\D?(\d{3})\D?\D?(\d{3})\D?(\d{4})$ //this matches (111) 222-3333 | 1112223333 | 111-222-3333
      }
    }
  });
```

once you have defined your pattern you can go ahead and use it:

```
<form class="custom" data-abide>
  <label>Phone Number
    <input type="text" pattern="phoneNumber" required>
  </label>
</form>
```

Here's a link to another useful site when in need of RegExp: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=phone+number&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20 - if you would like to match a different format take a look there.

Comment: I added the pattern  ` abc : /^([0-9]){5,6}$/ `